# Ternary conditions to find expmod?

Tags: javascript, sicp

I am reading [SICP in JS](https://source-academy.github.io/sicp/split/chapters/1.3.2.html) about a non-terminating example of ternary conditions:

```
function is_even(n) {
    return n % 2 === 0;
}

function expmod(base, exp, m) {
    const half_exp = expmod(base, exp / 2, m);
    return exp === 0 ? 1
           : is_even(exp) ? half_exp * half_exp % m
           : base * expmod(base, exp - 1, m) % m;
}

console.log(expmod(4, 3, 5))
```

It explains that:

> This would make the function not just inefficient, but actually
> non-terminating! The problem is that the constant declaration appears
> outside the conditional expression, which means that it is executed
> even when the base case exp === 0 is met.

I just cannot get its idea, when exp === 0, it terminate with 1 but why half_exp executed?

Comment: I don't see how this infinite recursion sample have anything to do with conditional operator... Basically `function expmod() {expmod();}`... Could you please clarify why you think conditional operator makes any difference here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The part you've misunderstood is how and when the variables are initialized, and not how the ternary works. The ternary would work as you thought, *if the interpreter had reached it*.

---

You've put the `half_exp` variable in a conditional expression and expected it to not evaluate its initializer until it is used.

**However, that's not how it works.**

All variable initialization statements (both `var`, `let` and `const`) **evaluate their initializer immediately** when the control reaches the statement, without checking whether the variable is used later; and store the ***value** of the initializer* to the variable.

You can see it by running the following snippet:

```js
const foo = console.log("I'm executed!")
//`foo` is never used, but the code will print "I'm executed!" anyway
```

You can also confirm this by looking at the [ECMAScript Specification](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-let-and-const-declarations-runtime-semantics-evaluation).

> *LexicalBinding* **:** *BindingIdentifier* *Initializer*
>
> 1. Let *bindingId* be StringValue of *BindingIdentifier*.
> 2. Let *lhs* be ResolveBinding(*bindingId*).
> 3. If IsAnonymousFunctionDefinition(*Initializer*) is **true**, then
>
>    a. Let *value* be NamedEvaluation of *Initializer* with argument *bindingId*.
> 4. Else,
>
>    a. **Let *rhs* be the result of evaluating *Initializer ****.
>    b. Let *value* be ? GetValue(*rhs*).
> 5. Return InitializeReferencedBinding(*lhs*, *value*).
>
> <sub>*: Emphasis mine.</sub>

So, as you can see, the interpreter won't wait for the variable to be used.

This means that in your code:

```js
      // v-------------------------------------------+
function expmod(base, exp, m) {                   // |
    const half_exp = expmod(base, exp / 2, m); // ---+
                  // ^^^^^^--- This will always be called
    // This line is not even reached!
    return exp === 0 ? 1
           : is_even(exp) ? half_exp * half_exp % m
           : base * expmod(base, exp - 1, m) % m;
}
```

...you have infinite recursion.

---

To get around the issue, we have to move that call into a conditional part. In your code, that's easy, as instead of writing a multiplication with itself, we can raise the value to its second power, eliminating one of the references:

```js
function is_even(n) {
    return n % 2 === 0;
}

function expmod(base, exp, m) {
    return exp === 0 ? 1
           : is_even(exp) ? expmod(base, exp / 2, m) ** 2 % m
           : base * expmod(base, exp - 1, m) % m;
}

console.log(expmod(4, 3, 5)) //4
```

In other cases, where there's no such straightforward way, we could've refactored the code otherwise, for example, using `if`s:

```js
function is_even(n) {
    return n % 2 === 0;
}

function expmod(base, exp, m) {
    if(exp === 0)
      return 1;
    if(is_even(exp)){
      // We are in a conditional statement, so it's safe to call:
      const half_exp = expmod(base, exp / 2, m)
      return half_exp * half_exp % m
    }
    return base * expmod(base, exp - 1, m) % m;
}

console.log(expmod(4, 3, 5)) //4
```

Comment: appreciate it deeply for the patient elaboration, thank you.

Answer (score 3):

You make a recursive call at the first line that is executed no matter what. This means the function is non-terminating aka an infinite loop.

```
function expmod(base, exp, m) {
    const half_exp = expmod(base, exp / 2, m); // <- recursive call
    // code ...
}
```

Recursive calls should always go paired with some sort of check to make sure that there is an exit point.

Comment: I assumed that `const half_exp = expmod(base, exp / 2, m);` is not a recursive call, because there is not a proceeding `return`. additionally, `expmod(base, exp / 2, m)` might not be evaluated until half_exp is applied.

Comment: In JavaScript a function is evaluated as soon as you call it. Assigning `expmod(base, exp / 2, m)` to `half_exp` will mean the recursive call is made right there and then, not when you use `half_exp`.

Answer (score 1):

> I just cannot get its idea, when `exp === 0`, it terminate with `1` but why half_exp executed?

No when `exp` is `0` the expression doesn't terminate with `1`. `exp === 0 ? 1: is_even(exp)` will evaluate to `1` and the whole expression will act as a condition for next ternary operator. As `1` is a trucy value so the whole expression will evaluate to `half_exp * half_exp % m`

```
//Initial expression
(exp === 0 ? 1
   : is_even(exp)) ? (half_exp * half_exp % m)
   : (base * expmod(base, exp - 1, m) % m);

//Put exp = 1
(1 === 0 ? 1
   : is_even(exp)) ? (half_exp * half_exp % m)
   : (base * expmod(base, exp - 1, m) % m);

//Evaluate the first ternary expression
(1) ? (half_exp * half_exp % m)
   : (base * expmod(base, exp - 1, m) % m);

//The result of first will convert to boolean
Boolean(1) ? (half_exp * half_exp % m)
   : (base * expmod(base, exp - 1, m) % m);

//The result of first expression acts as condition for second ternary operator
true ? (half_exp * half_exp % m)
   : (base * expmod(base, exp - 1, m) % m);

//As condition is true to first expression is returned
(half_exp * half_exp % m)
```

Comment: `true ? 1 : false ? 0 : 2` is evaluated as `true ? 1 : (false ? 0 : 2)`, not as `(true ? 1 : false) ? 0 : 2`.  So I don't think the following sentence is correct: *"`exp === 0 ? 1: is_even(exp)` will evaluate to `1` and the whole expression will act as a condition for next ternary operator."* You can test this out by running: `true ? 1 : false ? 0 : 2 //=> 1`

Comment: test with `true ? 1 : false ? 0 : 2 //=> 1`, ty.@3limin4t0r it will not.